# How to write custom inspector for tag, layer gameobject section?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Looking way to draw additional fields to top of gameobject inspector

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the top part of the inspector (you should change the basic documentation of Unity), but you can create a script with some `serializedObject` lists and then have them as strings.
For example, in [this tutorial](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/custom-list/) you can see how to create a selector of object in the inspector, instead of using something like that you can change it with strings.
In this way from the inspector, you can add new elements and write the custom tags. Via script, you can access your tags instead with a `compareTag` you can call the script and check if in the list there is your tag and it will work the same